# Wasm directly on holochain?

Tags: webassembly, holochain

I am looking for having a basic OS running on holochain, as it would possibly allow more computations/services to run directly from it, including from existing code designed for other platforms. I have saw that holochain can compile code to Wasm to use it over the network, my doubt is if I can get a code already compiled to Wasm to just be distributed over holochain